# SQL Server database mail script

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to send the mail through database with custom query using the
code below, and tried to send that data as a attachment as .csv extension it is working fine.

But when I am trying to select the data from by particular database table then it gives an error!

> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Please let me know if anyone has idea about this error.

Check the below query which is working fine for the custom select statement

```
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
   @profile_name='*****',
   @recipients='pt497@****.com',
   @subject= 'Database Mail XPs Test',
   @body= 'mail sent successfully!!!',
   @query= 'SELECT ''This'' AS Word1,''is''AS Word2,''a''AS Word3,''SQL''AS Word4,''genareted'' AS Word5        
  ,''CSV'' AS Word6,''File''AS Word7',
  @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
  @query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
  @query_result_separator = ';',
  @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```

It's working fine, but when I try to change the query like this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name='*****',
  @recipients='pt497@****.com',
  @subject= 'Database Mail XPs Test',
  @body= 'Hooray - mail sent successfully!!!',
  @query= 'select * from dbo.my_table_name',
  @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
  @query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
  @query_result_separator = ';',
  @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```

I get this error:

> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Comment: I added the db name to your query and it worked fine. 
@query= 'select * from MyDB.dbo.my_table_name'

Comment: check this: https://vijaypratapblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/15/failed-to-initialize-sqlcmd-library-with-error-number-2147024809/